# How to display the recipient address when sending via sendmail

Tags: linux, sendmail

I'm trying to send

```
sendmail -it email@example.com < email.eml
```

and recipient in "To" see empty or undisclosed recipients.

How to remove "undisclosed recipients" and display email of recipient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendmail` expects you to provide the headers in the standard input.

And the `-t` option tells it to get the recipients from the headers, so you don't need to include it as an argument.

```
{ echo "To: email@example.com"; echo; cat email.eml; } | sendmail -it
```

The empty `echo` is to put a blank line between the headers and the body.